# ss showing socket stuck in SYN-SENT with no traceable PID

Tags: socket, netstat, ss

On a client I see the following:

```
[root@redacted_local ~]# ss | grep -i syn                                   
SYN-SENT   0      1            redacted_local_ip:792             redacted_server_ip:nfs
```

This status has remained the same. I'm unable to actually track port 792/SYN_SENT statuses to a PID:

```
[root@redacted_local ~]# netstat -pnt | grep -i syn
tcp        0      1 redacted_local_ip:792            redacted_server_ip:2049             SYN_SENT    -
```

How can I tell what is actually holding this port open and what PID exists that needs to be killed? The client is using `autofs` to go to the NFS server and mount user directories, such that when a user logs into the client, they will have their home directory mounted from the NFS server. Is something even "stuck" in the first place that can be killed?

Comment: from the port value one can guess it's kernel's NFS client, which even if it started a thread (eg `NFSv4 callback`) wouldn't appear in resources because it doesn't use or show things like file descriptors etc: it's kernel code rather than userspace.

Comment: Thanks @A.B - yeah, I tried a number of things (like tracking down the inode and associating that to a PID) with no result. I think the only real solution here is to reboot the host.

Comment: or resolve the routing issue, or force umount the NFS mount...

Comment: Yeah, problem is, there is no actual NFS mount. These servers are authenticating with IPA and then using `autofs`/`automount` to actually call out to the NFS server to automatically map their usernames and mount their homedir directly on the host.

Comment: Then what is the mount type if not NFS in "mount their homedir directly on the host"?

Comment: `/proc/mounts` shows `auto.home /home/ipa_users autofs rw,relatime,fd=6,pgrp=27398,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,indirect 0 0` however `/etc/mtab` has no entry for any NFS mount, so attempting to actually unmount anything is not possible.

Comment: I have the EXACT SAME PROBLEM. Can't reboot the server though. :(

Comment: No routing issues (mount was working perfectly until my NFS rebooted), no NFS mounts... I am really stuck here. One more thing: I can see my NFS SERVER and VOLUME listed in /proc/net/nfsfs

Answer (score 1):

OK. I ended up finding a simple solution to this (annoying) issue.

My setup was like this:

```
 NFS CLIENT      ----\        NFS SERVER
10.0.1.20/24     ----/       10.0.1.21/24
```

I added a second IP address to NFS SERVER and changed the NFS CLIENT (which had the stuck TCP CONNECTION) to point to this second IP address.

```
 NFS CLIENT      ----\        NFS SERVER
10.0.1.20/24          )      10.0.1.21/24
                 ----/       10.0.1.22/24
```

Problem solved. No reboot.

Probably rebooting is a simpler option, but in my case I could not afford to do that.